# How does initWithCoder work in combination with Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, initialization, interface-builder, xib, nscoder

I have a subclass from `UITextField` that I use in Interface Builder to build my view (so I set the class of this object to MyCustomTextField in directly in Interface Builder).

Now, I understood that when the view gets loaded, the `initWithCoder`: method of `MyCustomTextField` will be invoked, so that I can do some initialization stuff. However, I also found that the attributes that I set in Interface Builder using the Attribute Inspector are NOT initialized in the way I set them!

Does anyone know why this is the case and how I can manage to set the properties of the instance of MyCustomTextField to the values that I set in the Attribute Inspector in Interface Builder?

Comment: Most initialization for UI classes should take place in the `awakeFromNib` method, not in `init`. Is it possible to move your "initialization stuff" to that method instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are probably not calling `[super initWithCoder:coder]` from your custom override of this method. The data is loaded from nib archive into the `UIView` instance in this super implementation. The correct implementation should look like:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (nil != self) {
        // extra initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```